# How to LIKE the fan page and post on wall through the application?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-wall, fan-page

### Current Scenario

Development Environment: Visual Studio with Facebook C# SDK
User has granted user_likes,email,publish_stream permissions to the application.
Application is able to get user information.
Application is able to post on the user wall.
Applicaion is able to retrieve (Fan) Page information.

### Requirement

- Application should be able to LIKE the (Fan) Page on behalf of the user. This is step is important as without this, user can not post on the Page
- Application should be able to post on the wall of (Fan) Page on behalf of user (Not admin of the page)

  C# code is not necessary to show as I'll convert into C# myslef. PHP or any other code will be ok for me or (walkthrough) steps, without any code will be fine also.
   Immediate response will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and probably never will be.  There is no API to like a fan page.  A user has to click a like button in the browser.